# Microsoft Access memory error when using CTRL-P to print the screen to either printer or PDF

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access-2013, mysql-connector

I am in the middle of converting an old ADP using MSSQL as the back end and Access 2002 runtime frontend to a MySQL backend and accdb Access 2013+ runtime frontend.

We are squashing little bugs but overall the process is complete and the new system is now the production system.

One interesting problem that appears to be getting worse is that when they want to print out what they see on the screen, they press CTRL-P to bring up the print dialog box. Then they either select their printer (one of a couple of different models of HP lasers) or their NitroPDF driver to save it as a PDF (they have been using Nitro since before Windows had a built-in PDF driver so that is just what they do).

Sometimes, access will appear to start spooling the job only to stop and pop up an error box saying "There isn't enough memory to update the display. Close unneeded programs and try again." There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason to when it happens although once it starts, it seems to keep generating that error until you reboot.

All systems have plenty of ram, and checking task manager does not show the system out of memory or even high in use. All are running 64bit Windows 10, two are using Access 2013 runtime 32bit, one is running the Access in Office 2019 Professional 32bit. All are up to date. All are running the 32bit version of the MySQL ODBC driver. This problem was not noted in the previous system which was 32bit all the way around too. (running 32bit because we had the old and new running side-by-side and I could not install the 32bit and 64bit on the same systems).

There are three users in the system all the time and they are all having this issue. It started with the one person running Office 2019, and now all three people have the issue. It is not limited to one recordset but does appear to only be an issue when they print a form with a subform. There are at least two forms, and those two forms have four or more subforms on different tabs. They select one tab to show its subform and hit CTRL-P, that is when they see the error, sometimes.

I know all of this is rather vague, I am more looking for directions to go to get more information to help diagnose the problem than I am looking for a specific solution.

Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see you use runtime. Do you have ability to re-design the frontend with full fledged MSACCESS.EXE installed?

Comment: Parfait: one of the three is using full access as part of Office 2019 Professional which I believe I mentioned. It happens in BOTH the runtime and full access.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this issue may not be fully reproducible but  dependent on users, CPU environments, even settings. Also, your form design can be the issue with width and length dimensions, overlapping objects to be redrawn, dense images and OLE objects, and other special controls like tabs causing the data overhead. Debug the issue by starting with simple design and one by one add your other controls.

However, forms are for user interaction and display and not intended for print outputs. If able, consider building corresponding reports of the form and subforms and have users click a button to send report to printer (default of [**DoCmd.OpenReport**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport)).

With this approach, you control the page setup and design output of the content with stability across users and CPU environments. Additionally, you can easily copy most form objects as report objects with guidance on letter size (portrait or landscape modes) to avoid cut-offs from wide or long formats of forms. Same recordsources can be used even pointing to form controls. Also, subforms mirror subreports but tab control may not translate, so you may have to separate that content by groupings, pages, or separate reports.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought too, just design reports for each tab they need to print out. Just thought that there may be something simple to resolve the issue since it did work previously but now does not. Forms and code has not really changed, only the ODBC driver and msaccess version have changed.

Comment: Access 2002 is quite a bit different than Access 2013! Again, it could be your form design where you might have an older type of control having issues with printing. Remove one by one and see. From the start, use forms for UX and reports for printers.